# Interaction with enum members in swift-based app

Tags: swift, object, enums, reference, sprite-kit

I'm beginning to teach myself swift and I'm going through examples of games at the moment. I've run across a line of code that I thought was peculiar

```
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

In languages I'm used to (C / Java) the "." notation is used to reference some sort of structure/ object but I'm not exactly sure what this line of code does as there is no specified object explicitly before the "."

Information regarding clarification of this non-specified "." reference, or when/ how it can be used, would be great

P.S. I'm using sprite kit in Xcode

Comment: Have you looked at what the definition of `scaleMode` is and researched the type that it is? Did you read the swift book?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, as in the other languages you mentioned, '.' is a member access operator. The syntax you are referring to is a piece of shorthand that Swift allows because it is a type-safe language.

The compiler recognises that the property you are assigning to is of type `SKSceneScaleMode` and so the value you are assigning must be one of that type's enumerated values - so the enumeration name can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, where did you learn to program iOS in swift? I've got plenty of programming experience but none with iOS app programming. I'd love any info on useful resources that may have helped you when you were beginning to learn swift iOS.

Comment: I don't really program iOS in Swift - I just see Swift code here on SO and I read the Swift book. I have been programming iOS in objective C for about 6 years. Swift is too much of a "work in progress" for me to trust it

Answer (score 0):

To add to PaulW11's answer<strike>, what's happening here is only valid syntax for enums, and won't work with any other type (class, struct, method, function).</strike> Swift knows the type of the property that you are assigning to is an enum of type `SKSceneScaleMode`, so lets you refer to the enum member without having to explicitly give the type of the enum (ie `SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill`).

There are some situations where there will be ambiguity, and you will have to give the full name, this will be dependant on the context. For example, you may have two different enum types in scope, that both have a matching member name.

**EDIT**

Updating this answers as I incorrectly specified this was only applicable to enums, which is not true. There is a good blog post here which explains in more detail

http://ericasadun.com/2015/04/21/swift-occams-code-razor/

Comment: Thank you as well! I'm just starting up with swift so any contextual info is much appreciated. Seems fitting that this only works for enums.

Comment: Updated my answer, as I gave the incorrect advice about this only be applicable to enums, which is not the case.